# Parsing Google OpenID Callback

Tags: c#, android, .net, model-view-controller, openid-connect

Long story short, I want to get an id_token back from Google using the OpenID Connect standard. I want to do this to authentication requests from a native Android app in order to use my MVC application like an API.

Problem is, when you set your "response_type=id_token" for the request to exchange your one-time access code with Google, it responds with the parameters in a url fragment: 
`http://mycallbackuri.com#id_token=<whatever>&refresh_token=<whatever>`

As you probably know, this fragment stuff doesn't ever touch the server. Usually I can put a Javascript middle-man in there, to handle the request and hash out the goodies, then POST them to my MVC endpoint.

In the case of Android requests, however, this becomes a problem: how am I supposed to preserve the original Android request when I have to make a *new* request to get the tokens on the server side?

Just as background, I have my Android app getting an access code from Google and  then sending it to my web application. The web application is supposed to exchange it for an id_token and then set up the necessary cookies for it to be authenticated.

Anybody know how I can accomplish this? Maybe there's a different flow I need to use, or I need to simply get an id_token in my app and send it along to my API, then verify the id_token, and mark the request as authenticated?

I can post code if you think it'll help.

Comment: Why not use the authorization code grant (aka. `code` flow) and have the backend exchange the `code` for an `id_token` and subsequently return the identity information to your app? The implicit flow that you use was designed to deliver the `id_token` to an in-browser application.

Comment: Well, that makes sense except that it's difficult to preserve the initial mobile request. Since Google sends information in a url fragment, I don't have access to it on the server unless I parse it with javascript and post it myself. This breaks the request-response chain, which makes it hard to send it back to the mobile app. But I could be wrong about all that.

Comment: when using the `code` flow, the `code` is sent as a query parameter

Comment: The `code`, yes, but when you specify your need for an `id_token` the response from Google that contains the `id_token` delivers it in a url fragment. I can get a `code` just fine, I just need the `id_token` in a way that touches the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response_type=id_token` will trigger the Implicit flow which delivers the token in the URL fragment, primarly meant to be used by in-browser clients.

Use `response_type=code` and make sure to add the `scope` `openid` to the Authentication Request so that you will get a `code` in the query parameter that the backend can pickup and subsequently get both an `access_token` and an `id_token` in the response from the token endpoint. This is called the OpenID Connect Basic Client profile, see: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#TokenOK

Comment: You're right - the authentication endpoint returns the `id_token` as a url fragment. The token endpoint does not! I ended up getting it to work. Thanks!